# How can a deleted heroku app be retrieved?

Tags: heroku

I have mistakenly deleted my app that i have deployed on heroku. i have deleted both the local and the remote versions of the code.
I'd like to know how to restore it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible I am afraid.

The Heroku Dashboard (in Settings) says "Deleting your app and its add-ons is irreversible".

The Command CLI provides the `apps:destroy` command but nothing to recover.